# Websocket server is not starting without admin rights

Tags: c#, websocket-sharp, admin-rights

My websocket server is not starting. I cannot connect. But if I run program with admin rights It's working.

```
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Resource.UZCRYPTO);
            using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                if (!store.Certificates.Contains(certificate))
                    store.Add(certificate);
            }

            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Resource._127_0_0_1, "1", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            //WebCoket set
            WebSocketServer wssv = new WebSocketServer(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4141, true);
            wssv.SslConfiguration.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(cert);
            wssv.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
            wssv.AddWebSocketService<WebSocketEcho>("/");
            wssv.KeepClean = false;
            wssv.Start();
```

Comment: If you use the WPF tag you don't have a server to begin with. You have a desktop application that wants to act as a server, making changes to the machine that require admin rights. Most malware would like to do the same changes (open up and listen to ports), which is why it's not allowed

Comment: Worse, your code is forcing the use of weaker SSL algorithms. What are you trying to do? Why does your *desktop* application try to act as a Websocket server? And why hard-code the TLS version instead of letting the OS pick the strongest available, like TLS1.3 on Windows 11?